# Usercontrol not adding controls dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a user control that inherits from Panel, and I added a collection of LinkLabel:

```
public partial class MyPanel : Panel
{
    private BindingList<LinkLabel> items;

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public BindingList<LinkLabel> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
    }

    public MyPanel ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        this.items = new BindingList<LinkLabel>();
        this.items.ListChanged += ItemListChanged;
    }

    private void ItemListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (Controls[i] is LinkLabel)
            {
                Controls.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        var location = new Point(20, 40);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Controls.Add(item);

            if (item.Visible)
            {
                item.Location = location;
                location.Y += item.Height + 4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when items are added to the list at the design time I add them to the `Controls` collection.

However, ItemListChanged is not being fired. What am I missing?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any handling of adding controls at design time. When you add controls at design time, they are added to the Controls collection, not to your BindingList. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Why don't you just override the `OnControlAdded` / `OnControlRemoved` methods and handle the `.Controls` collection?

Comment: Is this meant to handle the layout of the LinkLabel controls? To prevent adding controls of a different type? (Btw, this is a Custom Control, not a UserControl)

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Could you share the actual requirement as well?

Comment: How did you add the list? The event "ListChanged" occurs when the list or an item in the list changes.